# Why does this Java listString Method don't work?

Tags: java, list

i have a Stringlist with stuff allready inside of it, this Code should replace a String in the List.
The courious thing for me is, that it works all fine if i replace the headString [0] but if I try i > 0 it wont replace it

```
public String replaceStringAt(int i, String text) {
    Item node = head;
    Item item = new Item(text);
    int indexCounter=0;
    
    
    while(node!=null && indexCounter < i) {
        
        node = node.next;
        indexCounter++;
    }
    if(i == 0) {
        item.next = head.next; 
        head = item;
    }else {
        item.next = node.next;
        node = item;
        
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want to replace the second item in the list, the entry with i = 1.

The loop leaves 'node' pointing at the old item.

Now you point the 'next' of the new item to the 'next' of the old item. So far so good.

Then you point the internal variable 'node', previously pointing at the old item, to the new item. This has no point to it.

The 'next' of the predecessor of the old item is still pointing at the old item. Nowhere do you point that predecessor to the new item. You have not linked the new item into the list.

You absolutely need to update the predecessor in the chain.  You can do this with a single pointer variable, but it needs to locate the predecessor, not the item being replaced.  (The item being replaced is at predecessor.next, of course).

The root cause of this might be confusion between objects and references to objects.  Variables only hold references, so 'node = item' affects nothing except the variable 'node'.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot, i am still at the beginning with lists yet :)

I addet a second node wich follows the first node in the loop and let this later point at the Item .